# Jacobi field and the metric

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I'm reading about Jacobi fields lately, and have noticed some features of it (and it's derivative) with respect to the metric. Thinking about that, I had an non-based, purely intuitive thought that the following feature may holds, but I have a really weak proving skills (I'm just reading related book in my spare time, my last formal education was calculus and some linear algebra 15 years ago). I was hoping to get this clarified.

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold, and let $\gamma_s(t)=\exp_p(t(v+su))$ where $u,v\in T_pM$ for some $p\in M$. Assume M have a non-positive sectional curvature, show that $g(J(t),J'(t))>0$ , where $g,J$ are the metirc tensor, and the Jacobi field of $\gamma_s$ respectively.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics! To attract answers to your question, please add some context and background information.  For example, where did you encounter this problem (e.g. a book, class, etc.)?  Please also show your attempt; seeing your work helps us help you.  If this is homework, please [read this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1803/23353).

Comment: @anorton some background was added. thanks for the greetings.

Answer (score 0):

Let $T(t)=\dot{\gamma_0}(t)$ we have 
$$D_Tg(J,J')=g(J',J')+g(J,J'')$$
$$=|J'|^2-g(J,R(J,T)T))$$
$$=|J'|^2-K(J,T)(|J|^2|T|^2-g^2(T,J))\ge 0$$
So $g(J,J')$ is increasing and $g(J(0),J'(0))=g(0,J'(0))=0$.

Comment: Thanks, but don't we have $g(J',J')+g(J,J'')\geq 0$ anyway as the metric is positive definite? if so, negative sectional curvature is not necessary. what am I missing here?

Comment: metric is positive definite means $g(X,X)\ge 0 \forall X$